# javac not recognized

Tags: java, path, javac

What can I do when I keep receiving the error

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

when I want to compile my jar or `.class` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Make sure %JAVA_HOME%/bin is on your %PATH% (or $JAVA_HOME on the $PATH in *nix).

Answer (score 7):

It means that it is not in your path.  You have the following options:

1) Change to the directory where javac lives before calling it.

2) Use the full path to javac when making the call, e.g. C:\java\jdk1.6.0_12\bin\javac ...

3) Add the javac directory to the PATH environment variable

Answer (score 6):

This just means that javac isn't in your PATH variable.

On Windows, you just have to add the folder that contains javac.exe to the PATH environment variable (Win+Pause/Break).

On Linux/Mac/Unix, just append that directory to $PATH in .bashrc or similar.

Comment: +1 for the windows shortcut to the "My Computer" "Properties" page. :)

Answer (score 4):

The error that you are seeing is generated by Windows, and isn't specific to Java. That error means that you typed a command and Windows could not find the command by that name.

The easiest way of rectifying the situation is to ensure that Java is properly installed in your system's `PATH`.

First, ensure that you have a JDK installed (and not just a JRE). Your next best bet is to add an environment variable called `JAVA_HOME` and point it at the base install directory for the version of Java that you installed.

Next, modify your `PATH` environment variable by prepending the string `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;` to whatever is already in your `PATH`. If you look at the contents of that directory, you will see that `javac` is in there (along with a number of other Java development tools).

Answer (score 2):

You have to install JDK (which includes javac compiler) and ensure that it's in the path. See http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp

Answer (score 2):

**[Common Error Messages from SUN Tutorial page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Step 4 (Update the PATH variable) of the [JDK installation instructions](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/install/jdk/install-windows.html) explains what you should do to make it so that you can just type `javac` in the command prompt window.

Answer (score 1):

The link below gives a step by step explanation on how to set up java_home and path variables.
[JAVA_HOME setup](https://sites.google.com/site/javaerrorsandsolutions/home/java_home-setup)

Answer (score 1):

Even if I had

- JDK installed
- `JAVA_HOME` defined
- `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` present in my `%PATH%`

I still had this error. I resolved it by eliminating the JRE from my path variable. It was put before `JAVA_HOME`, has no `javac`. It seems Windows can't find `javac` in `JAVA_HOME\bin` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

***For Windows***

**Control Panel** > **System**...Then click **Advanced System Setting** (left pane)...then popup window will open...then click **Environment Variables**...Then another window will open...click **New** and add enter information below

**Variable name**: PATH

**Variable value**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin [**make sure this is the right path for you*]

Then it should work

Answer (score 0):

- Check whether you have JDK installed; if not installed, Install
- If JDK is installed, navigate into the bin folder of the installation, and try to execute javac.
- If javac executes, proceed (+:
- If javac does not execute, check your system path, and java path, and return to 2 above!