# compiling java programs

Tags: java, compilation, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javac not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299750/javac-not-recognized)

I'm starting in the world of programming in java and I have run across a big problem: i cant compile my programs. when I type the `javac` command in `cmd.exe`(im using Windows 7) it displays this:

> 'javac' is not recognized as an internal  or external command, operable program or batch file.

So I can't even test my first program.
I found in a book the following command:

```
set path=%path%;c:\java\jdk1.6.0\bin
```

but it doesnt work either.

I downloaded the newest version of the Jdk package just 2 weeks ago.

Comment: If you have Java 7 then '...\jdk1.6.0\...' won't be what you put in the path.  Find what the directory is actually named and put that in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Look through your C drive for the c:\java folder and make sure you have version 1.6.0 of the jdk

```
c:\java\jdk1.6.0\bin
```

This will only work if you give it a path that actually exists.  If you don't have 1.6.0, then type in:

```
set path=%path%;c:\java\<YOUR_ACTUAL_JAVA_VERSION_DIRECTORY>\bin
```

Comment: Also, your Java folder might be in C:\Program Files\Java...