# Javac Not found after setting the path

Tags: java, class

I was messing around with writing Java code without an ide, and compiling/running with command prompt. When I try to create the .class, I get an error saying that Javac is not recognized. I was looking for answers when I found this thread `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299750/javac-not-recognized`
But nothing was working. I have done the following

- Set C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin as a path
- Set the path in the command line
- Reinstalled the jdk

It also should be noted that If I had the .class then `java Main.class` will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the path you are using (`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin`), it most likely is a JRE.

`javac` is part of the JDK.

Also, you should use a recent version of Java 8.

- Oracle Java 8u202 (last version before the licence change)
- [Adopt OpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot) (the link point to the JDK 8).

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize there was a difference

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\bin` is the path to the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) - normally installed together with the JDK; or as standalone (without JDK);
try `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin`, assuming the **JDK** (Java Development Kit) was installed there. Anyway it must be the directory where  `javac.exe` is located.

Note: the last sentence is probably not correct: 
`java Main.class` will try to start the **class** `Main.class` found in file `Main.class.class`. 
Probably,  to start the `Main` class it should be `java Main`

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly now. I did not have the jdk